# Ordenar Alfabeticamente um ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Eu tenho um ArrayList chamado Teste com os campos:

```
public class Teste 
{
    private String dctitle;
    private String rdfabout;
    private String dbid;
    private String depto;
    private String sigla;
    private String ciclo;
    private String state;
    private String dataplanejadainicial;
    private String dataEntradaEstado;
    private String id;
    private String executante;
}
```

Esse ArrayList tem N itens e eu preciso criar um método "ordenaPorDepto" que vai receber como parâmetro o `ArrayList<Teste> teste` e me retornar um ArrayList com os Testes ordenados pelos Departamentos. 
Sei que tem um método chamado *.sort* mas não sei como usar.

***OBS.: na classe Teste estão implementados todos os Get e Set dos atributos, só não coloquei para não deixar a pergunta muito grande***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) com a [Interface Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) para ordernar o mesmo `array`, ***exemplo minimo***:

```
Teste a = new Teste();
a.setDepto("3");
Teste b = new Teste();
b.setDepto("2");
Teste c = new Teste();
c.setDepto("1");

ArrayList<Teste> testes = new ArrayList<>();
testes.add(a);
testes.add(b);
testes.add(c);


Collections.sort(testes, new Comparator(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Teste a1 = (Teste)o1;
        Teste a2 = (Teste)o2;
        return a1.getDepto()
                .compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getDepto());
    }

});
```

***ou***

```
Collections.sort(testes, new Comparator<Teste>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Teste o1, Teste o2) {                
        return o1.getDepto()
                .compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getDepto());
    }
});
```

***ou***

Se quiser ordena inclusive palavras acentuadas:

```
Collections.sort(testes, new Comparator<Teste>(){
    private Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);            
    @Override
    public int compare(Teste o1, Teste o2) {    
        return getCollator().compare(o1.getDepto(), o2.getDepto());                
    }

    public Collator getCollator() {
        collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
        return collator;
    }

});
```

[Exemplo ONLINE Ideone](https://ideone.com/D6fUBT)

***Referencias:***

- [Interface Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
- [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)
- [Ordenar um ArrayList?](http://www.guj.com.br/t/ordenar-um-arraylist/27792)

Comment: então, eu estou tentando entender como funciona esse .sort
ele me retorna um novo array já em ordem, desde o primeiro item até o ultimo?

Comment: Isso @MariTeixeira ele vai pegar aquele `array` e ordenar pra você todos os elementos contidos, no caso eu fiz a comparação no `getDepto()` que seria o departamento!. na verdade é o mesmo array ordenado.

Comment: @MariTeixeira ficou claro a resposta?

Comment: ficou... eu só estou me confundindo na utilização. Eu pensei em criar um "novo array" já ordenado pq vou ter que utilizar esse array em outros métodos também. Como essa função `.sort` não retorna um novo, ela altera o array que está sendo passado como parâmetro, eu tenho que fazer esse método `Collections.sort`a cada vez que eu precisar dele ordenado?

Comment: @MariTeixeira se vai utilizar somente quando ele não estiver ordenado e claro você precisar ordena-lo, exemplo mudança no array, como aumentar o `array` como novos itens...

Comment: eu vou ter que utilizar ele **sempre** ordenado

Comment: eu consegui! Obrigada, estava me confundindo mas agora eu consegui!